# Different formatter's field by file extension

Tags: theming, nodes

I have Drupal 7 and a file field and users can upload pdf, office documents and image. For pdf i have pdf.js formatter, office doc's have simple link to download and image show by fancybox plugin. I am need use different formatters if file have different extension.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work for me =)

`$field_link_file = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_docs_files');
$file_url = file_create_url($field_link_file[0]['uri']);
$parts = pathinfo($file_url);
$extension = $parts['extension'];
    if ($extension == 'jpg' || $extension == 'png' || $extension == 'tif') {
    $options = array(
    'type' => 'colorbox',
    'label' => 'hidden',
    'settings' => array(
        'colorbox_node_style' => 'large',
        'colorbox_node_style_first' => ''
  )
);
    }
    elseif ($extension == 'pdf') {
  $options = array(
  'type' => 'pdf_default',
  'label' => 'hidden',
  'settings' => array(
    'width' => '100%',
    'height' => '800px'
  )
);
}
    else {
        $options = array(
  'type' => 'text',
  'label' => 'hidden',
  'settings' => array(
    'width' => '100%',
    'height' => '800px'
  )
);
    }
  $field_view_files = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_docs_files', $options);
  print render($field_view_files);`